# Segmentation fault in specific situation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

Hello guys I am a C learner and I have wrote a program to solve the shortest path problem (simple version) (by implementing simulated annealing algorithm) but I get a **problem at execution time**. when I run the debugger in Code::blocks it gave me a **segmentation fault in line mixer** (see code) but I dont know why. The surprising thing now is that when I remove the loop or set a specific number (tested 100 iteration) it runs correctly, but when I set it high for example 1000 it stops. So what do you think is causing the problem (If you wish to see the full code I can post it, I just don't know how and most of it is written in french so excuse me). Any help is appreciated. Link to the project : https://gist.github.com/melkanas/a1909439f6c3f9a33b8552a04ddadd77
EDIT :: I think it is a stackoverflow error because the problem happens only when I try a large number of iterations ( not infinite).

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    double temperature = (double) 1000;
    int choix = 1; //choice
    int i = 0;
    Tour *Trajet =NULL;
    Tour *Meilleur = NULL; // the best solution
    Tour *nouveauTour =NULL; //the new randomly generated combination
    Tour *nettoyer = NULL; // to free memory of old (not referenced anymore)
    int tailleTrajet =0;
    double probalea =0; // random (probability related to the algorithme
    double ratio = 0.0001; // to minimize temperature
    int nombreAleatoire = 0; // to divide the trajectory into two pieces
    printf("Creation du Tour"); //
    while(choix)
    {
        Ville *V = malloc(sizeof(Ville));
        V->nom = malloc(sizeof(char)*TAILLE_MAX);
        i++;
        printf("Ville Num %d\n",i);
        initialiserVille(V);
        Trajet = InsererEnQueue(&Trajet,*V);
        free(V);
        printf("votre choix (0/1): ");
        scanf("%d",&choix);
    }
    printf("Tour initiale: \n");
    AffichageTour(Trajet);
    printf("\nAvec une distance de %lf",distanceTour(Trajet));
    Meilleur = Trajet;
    tailleTrajet = Trajet->taille;
    int q =1; // this is just to count the number of iteration before the 
              //program stops
    //this part underneath is where the mess
    while(temperature>1)
    {
        nombreAleatoire = (int) rand()%(tailleTrajet-1) +1;
        nouveauTour = mixer(Trajet,nombreAleatoire); // creates a new 
                                            //Trajectory (allocates memory)
        probalea = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
        double pro = probabilite(distanceTour(Trajet),distanceTour(nouveauTour),temperature);
//returns 1 if new Trajectory is best(short or long but has a good probability) //else 0
        if(pro>probalea )
        {
            Trajet = nouveauTour;
        }
        else
        {
            Liberer(nouveauTour); //free new generated solution(not a good solution)
            nouveauTour = NULL;
        }
        if(distanceTour(Trajet)<distanceTour(Meilleur))
        {
            nettoyer = Meilleur; // to keep the old best solution
            Meilleur = Trajet; // move to the new best
            Liberer(nettoyer); // dealocate memory (last best)
            nettoyer =NULL;
        }
        temperature=temperature*((double)(1.0-ratio)); // the cast was just to make sure(after the problem occured)
        printf("\n iteration : %d",q);// minimiser la temperature
        q++;
    }
    printf("Trajet optimal :\n"); // shows the best(shortest) trajectory
    AffichageTour(Meilleur);
    printf("\nAvec une distance de %lf",distanceTour(Meilleur));
```

Comment: what is the mixer function? if the seg fault is happening in the mixer, we should check that out.

Comment: the mixer just returns a new Trajectory which is the the mix of two given trajectories I already tested the mixer and it works the problem  is that the mixer uses a function called alternance which uses a function called InsererEnQueue. is there a way to upload the code ?

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can determine the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem is not related to stackoverflow or anything it is just an attribute of a structure which is an integer is not initialised in the function mixer.